# Convert Array to Type Array

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I'm creating a generic object from DB data:

```
object[] data = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];
dataReader.GetValues(data);
T t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), data);
```

But, types with no constructor error on the third line. I want to add an `if`:

```
if (typeof(T).GetConstructor(data.TypesOf()) != null)
```

`data.TypesOf()` is actually an array - `Type[]` - that contains all types of the objects in `data`.

What is the equivalent to `data.TypesOf()` that really works?

Or do I need to iterate `data` and build it myself?

Comment: `data` is always an `object[]` - it has no relation to `typeof(T)` whatsoever, since it is just the values from the reader. What are you trying to represent with `data.TypesOf()` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell. `data.TypesOf()` is a `Type[]` array which contains the types of `data`. In order, at that. Added to question.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming your `object[]` is containing values that are, for example, an `int`, a `string` and a `float`, and you are trying to resolve a constructor of the form `public T(int,string,float)`. To get the types, you could use:

```
var types = Array.ConvertAll(data, x => x.GetType());
```

But that won't actually help you much here, since that is pretty-much what `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), data)` has *already tried to do* - so if `Activator` failed, I don't see that it is obvious that you're going to do any better - unless the key difference is that the constructor is non-public and you are going to supply some `BindingFlags`.

Personally, though, I would suggest that it is easier to bind by *name* than by position; there are tools like [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) that will do *all of that for you*, allowing you to use simply:

```
var data = conn.Query<SomeType>(sql, args).ToList();
```

for example:

```
int userId = 12345;
var users = conn.Query<User>("select * from Users where Id = @userId",
      new {userId}).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tool. I was actually trying to avoid ORM since I understood it costs in performance and load on DB. I'd like to hear your stand on this, though not here since it's off topic.

Comment: @JNF I don't think that is off topic - and your concern is reasonable, but unfounded. We actually wrote dapper to *avoid* all the performance problems with ORMs - it is a micro-ORM, not a full ORM. It doesn't do anything more than **materialization** (turning row data into objects), and it does that *brutally* efficiently (it uses raw IL generation internally, which it caches (the IL), etc). We profile it extensively: it is basically exactly the same speed as hand-rolled `IDataReader` code, but without the human errors.

Comment: @JNF but yes, *in the general case*, ORMs can be slow - Entity Framework and NHibernate in particular have a lot of complexity and overhead (although I've seen both teams try to improve performance lately). The micro-ORMs are simply in a whole different performance area, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you are trying to get types of elememnts of an object array. So you can do something like:

```
 var ctorArgsTypes = data.Select(d => d.GetType()).ToArray()

 var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(ctorArgsType);

 // check if appropriate ctor exists
 if (ctor == null)
     throw something

 T t = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), data);
```

Comment: Right. I was trying to figure out if a built in method exists, instead of invoking a LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the [Activator.CreateInstance(Type, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) method, for the `Object[]` paramter :

> An array of arguments that match in number, order, and type the
>   parameters of the constructor to invoke. If args is an empty array or
>   null, the constructor that takes no parameters (the default
>   constructor) is invoked.

So maybe in your case, your `data` object is not typed for each value (if getting from a DB or a file). You need to find a way to "type" your objects in your `data` array.

Comment: @JNF are you *sure* about that? In particular, mismatches are (I say with confidence from my micro-ORM work) common between `single` / `double` / `decimal`, and `short` / `int` / `long`. I **strongly** suggest looking at what the `Array.ConvertAll(data, x => x.GetType())` says before boldly saying "No. Types are OK.". If the types were OK, `Activator` would have already found the constructor.

Comment: @MarcGravell - sure. I checked my data. Didn't yet run into the problem you're describing, so it's not the issue here. Will be, perhaps another time. :)

Comment: @JNF in that case: is the constructor non-public? Put simply, it is *either* a data mismatch, or a non-public constructor.

Comment: @MarcGravell, to make it clearer - sometimes I would explicitly use the function for a type with no constructors. Say `int`.

Comment: @JNF then... why do you have code that is looking for a constructor? Also: dapper's `Query<int>(sql, args)` would handle that fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29530/discussion-between-jnf-and-marc-gravell)

Comment: @MarcGravell it's a generic code that decides if it should use a constructor or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Type.GetTypeArray(object[])`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypearray(v=vs.110).aspx